# Curl multipart request as raw using netcat

Tags: bash, curl, netcat

I user Copy as Url and got

```
curl URL
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryKREAPjXwhB1bIgsq' \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SM-A750F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
--data-raw $'------WebKitFormBoundaryKREAPjXwhB1bIgsq\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Id"\r\n\r\n4578\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryKREAPjXwhB1bIgsq\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Name"\r\n\r\nHL PACK 1 \r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryKREAPjXwhB1bIgsq--\r\n' \
  --compressed
```

In above multipart data is name="Id" 5478, name="Name" HL PACK 1
i have file with:

```
4578, HL PACK 1
9990, HL PACK 2
```

i have file with Id and Name data and i want to generate curl request for all them

How can we rewrite above using -F flags ??

Tried

```
-F Id="" -F Name=""
```

but doesn't work

OR

How can we use `netcat` to get raw multipartboundary data string encoded request and use that to send as raw data

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add i) an example of your file with Id and Name, and ii) the output you expect from that example input.